# Provide Response to user who call the RestApi without waiting for the microservice rest call using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate, asyncresttemplate

I am developing a web API for an application. I had got a situation where the user will send a few data to my API. After processing the data I have to forward a few data to other API.

But I don't want to concentrate on the response from the second API to where I had called.

After calling the second API I want to send my response to the user without waiting for the second API response. 
Can anyone tell me how to handle this situation?

My API is written in JAVA spring boot REST, The Second API to where am calling is in PYTHON.

Comment: use @Async in your method(springboot)

Comment: can u send me example

Comment: add@Async on method which will provide response and add@EnableAsync on main springboot application that's it

Comment: Start the processing in a background thread and return `HTTP 202 Accepted`. It is customary to return a URL where the client and query the status of their job, such us `/status?id=xxyyzz`, as part of the 202 response.

Comment: Alternatively learn WebFlux.

Answer (score 1):

`@Async` will make it execute in a separate thread, i.e. the caller will not wait for the completion of the called method.

> Limitations

- it must be applied to public methods only
- self-invocation – calling the async method from within the same class
  – won’t work

Example:
[Spring Doc](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/), [Example 1](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async), [Example 2](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-creating-asynchronous-methods-using-as)